# wordpress plugin license issue -New plugin development

Tags: plugins, php

Can i copy all the codes of a free plugin and paste it in my new plugin ?. Is there any license issue for using the others plugin code. My new plugin is working properly ,but for making this plugin i copy the resources of other free plugin .

Comment: That is a question to ask a lawyer. Just because something is free doesn't mean it is legal to copy its code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find out how the plugin is licensed that you are going to use. Then read the details of that licence. Usually the least to do is to mention the author and/or name of the plugin used. For reference WordPress is licensed under GPLv2 (or later).

- [The WordPress License](http://wordpress.org/about/license/)